# Ruby on Rails - make count with name group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm tying to show active user names using this code:

```
<%= User.count(:activeuser, :distinct => true, :group => 'name') %>
```

currently it showing this ugly result:

```
{"Webster"=>0, "Wilfrid"=>0, "Winifred"=>0, "Nicolas"=>1, "Cage"=>1}
```

how can i make this pretty? like showing only true users Nicolas and Cage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter a Hash to include only items that meet particular criteria, use [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select):

```
hsh = {"Webster"=>0, "Wilfrid"=>0, "Winifred"=>0, "Nicolas"=>1, "Cage"=>1}

hsh.select {|key, val| val > 0 }
# => {"Nicolas"=>1, "Cage"=>1}
```

...or, to exclude items, [Hash#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-reject):

```
hsh.reject {|key, val| val.zero? }
# => {"Nicolas"=>1, "Cage"=>1}
```